# Error: Request of type 'PUBLIC_requestAccounts' already pending for origin http://localhost:3000. Please wait

Tags: javascript, next.js, ethereum, metamask

At some point, an error suddenly occurs and does not connect to your wallet.

```
if (window.ethereum) {
    console.log("11")
    const connect = async () => {
        const account = await window.ethereum.request({
            method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        })
        console.log("account:", account) //nothing
    }
    connect()
    console.log("22")
}
}
}
```

console:
"11"
"22"

I tried reinstalling Chrome, refreshing the page, deleting the cache... but I can't solve this problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and share more details e.g  of the frameworks you are using, e.g metamask. It looks like it is not an issue on your end but rather you missing a step that may be required before sending a new request.

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem. Maybe you have other ethereum wallets in your extension. Like Trust wallet, when I disabled other wallets, it went ok.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35157441)